# Sql Joining 3 Tables Query for Loan Total Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to get the total of Customer Loan from 3 tables the two tables are given loan to sum and the other subtract the paid amount and the tables have Customer ID in common. so far I can get the result only if the Customer ID exist in all tables but if it doesn't exist in one table I won't get Customer in my result. or I get NULL customer IDs when I anchor to the customer.

```
SELECT 
  AS1.C_ID AS [Customer ID],
  ISNULL(AS1.OldCustomerLoan, 0) AS [Old Loan],
  ISNULL(AS2.NewGivenLoan, 0) AS [New Given Loan],
  ISNULL(AS3.LoanPaid, 0) AS [PaidLoanAmount],
  (ISNULL(AS1.OldCustomerLoan, 0) + 
  ISNULL(AS2.NewGivenLoan, 0) - 
  ISNULL(AS3.LoanPaid,0) ) AS Total 
FROM
  Customer C
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT 
       MOC.C_ID,
       SUM(MOC.Quantity) AS OldCustomerLoan 
    FROM 
       Money_On_Customer MOC (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY 
       MOC.C_ID) AS1 
    ON c.C_Id = AS1.C_Id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT 
       NGL.C_ID 
       ,SUM(NGL.G_Take_Loan) AS NewGivenLoan 
    FROM 
       Given_Loan NGL   
    GROUP BY 
       NGL.C_ID) AS2
    ON c.C_Id = AS2.C_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       GLP.C_ID, SUM(GLP.G_P_Loan) AS LoanPaid 
    FROM 
       Given_Loan_Paid GLP 
    GROUP BY 
       GLP.C_ID ) AS3
ON c.C_Id = AS3.C_Id
```

Here Is a picture of my two results:

[When I get NULL Customer IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dRUU.png)

[When I don't get All the Customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyOaB.png)

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. Plese use enough sentences & phrases & words & periods & capitals. Please include text as text not as links/images. Please read & act on [mcve]. Eg give input & desired output. Eg post the smallest code with your problem.

Comment: @philipxy I've done the best I could

Comment: Obviously not, since you did nothing I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use c.c_id for the first column

In order to only get records where they exist in at least one of the tables you can add this to you query, just put you current query in place of the dots, and add the leftid col

```
Select * 
From
(Select c.c_id custonerid, 
        Coalesce(Coalesce(as1.c_id,as2.c_id),as3.c_id) leftid,......
 From ....
) ilv
Where leftid is not null
```

You might be able to just add

```
Where coalesce(coalesce(as1.c_id,as2.c_id),as3.c_id) is not null
```

To then end of your query

Comment: Why, it is the damn answer, not a comment. sick of trying to help when all you get is ridicule.

Comment: @AbBennett Hey Thank you But now I have Zero values rows how can I get rid of that?

Comment: if you referring to the columns from the tables you left outer join to, that is because no data exists in them, and the isnull is making them 0

Comment: @AbBennett Yh How can I only get the rows that have data in any one of the 3 tables

Comment: You want to suppress customers who  do not have Money_On_Customer and  Given_Loan and Given_Loan_Paid?

Comment: @AbBennett Thank you again, yes it works but now I want to change the NULL to 0

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, Thank you I've found now how with the help of Ab bennet

Comment: Which column has a null? And just use coalesce(...,0)

Comment: @AbBennett Thank you, I appreciate your help. its good to have people who can help you with your problems instead of arguing about the question. Thank You, it works now :) !

Comment: No problem, that's how stackoverflow should be

Answer (score 0):

@Ab Bennett's answer is right,
because you should use your main(master) table's primary key column
if Customer ID is not available in as1 (Money_On_Customer) it will show null.
Hope you understand my explanation.

**UPDATE:**

and use following for getting customer id

```
COALESCE(c.C_Id, AS1.C_Id, AS2.C_Id)
```

you will get first not null Customer ID

Comment: Yes, Thank You. But now I only want to get the rows that have data in any one of the 3 tables, if it doesn't have any it won't show.

Answer (score -1):

Here is My answer with the help of @Ab Bennett

```
Select * 
  From
  ( 
   SELECT 
     C.C_Name AS [Customer ID],
     ISNULL(AS1.OldCustomerLoan, 0) AS [Old Loan],
     ISNULL(AS2.NewGivenLoan, 0) AS [New Given Loan],
     ISNULL(AS3.LoanPaid, 0) AS [PaidLoanAmount],
     (ISNULL(AS1.OldCustomerLoan, 0) + 
     ISNULL(AS2.NewGivenLoan, 0) - 
     ISNULL(AS3.LoanPaid,0) ) AS Total 
   FROM
    Customer C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT 
        MOC.C_ID,
        SUM(MOC.Quantity) AS OldCustomerLoan 
   FROM 
       Money_On_Customer MOC (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY 
       MOC.C_ID) AS1 
    ON c.C_Id = AS1.C_Id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT 
       NGL.C_ID 
       ,SUM(NGL.G_Take_Loan) AS NewGivenLoan 
       FROM 
       Given_Loan NGL   
    GROUP BY 
    NGL.C_ID) AS2
    ON c.C_Id = AS2.C_Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT 
       GLP.C_ID, SUM(GLP.G_P_Loan) AS LoanPaid 
    FROM 
       Given_Loan_Paid GLP 
    GROUP BY 
       GLP.C_ID ) AS3
   ON c.C_Id = AS3.C_Id) ilv
   Where not ([Old Loan] = 0 and [New Given Loan]=0 and PaidLoanAmount =0 )
```

Comment: This is incorrect as two rows in a left table could total 0, ie a 2 and a -2. You are filtering these out. Use null to test for existence . You can't assume that can't happen